# How to show systray tooltip longer than 128 characters

Tags: winapi, notifications, notification-area

According to MSDN, [`NOTIFYICONDATA::szTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352%28VS.85%29.aspx) only supports 128 characters of text. How do I workaround this limitation and show longer tooltip text?

Comment: It is a hard limit, no workaround. Tips are supposed to be short and snappy.  There's preciously little space in the notification area anyway.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Standard tooltips (TOOLINFO) support much longer text and a simple example is hovering over an office document icon in Explorer. Seems reasonable to want this for notification area tooltips. Also of course there's a workaround! I could create my own topmost window for example, but I'm asking for the *most practical* workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's a documented limit in the MSDN, then you can't supply a string that is longer than that. Are you trying to display something similar to a balloon tip?

Keep in mind that this is a tooltip, and such designed to give brief information about an event. If you need something longer, then you will have to draw your own custom window in the tray area.

Maybe take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/LiviuBirjegaCode.aspx